# how to embed a angular2 app into the html page provided by ghost

Tags: angular, ghost-blog

I am using the ghost blog, it is still based on jquery. I wonder how would I be able to embed a angular2 application into the html page of ghost blog？

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound like a good idea but you can try embedding with an iframe. The routing will probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull all your content down using the API via ajax with angular, you won't benefit from any HTML page caching.

Nonetheless, it is possible.

If you want it on a particular post or page within Ghost, you can use script tags directly in the editor, or in Ghost 1.0, use [code injection in posts](https://help.ghost.org/article/20-post-settings#code-injection).

Alternatively, you can build a theme that uses angular. There's an example theme [here](https://github.com/patrickdbakke/ghost-angular) although it's very old.